# Determining no of processors and cores

Tags: multithreading, processors

I have a Dell Inspiron 620. The System control panel says 1 Intel i3-2100. Intel says (http://ark.intel.com/products/53422/) it has 2 cores and four threads. Three questions: In system environment variables the no_of_processors=4; so is that 4 threads?

Regarding the cores, when I run this code:

```
               // get a list of all processor devices
                deviceList = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref processorGuid, "ACPI", IntPtr.Zero, (int)DIGCF.PRESENT);
                // attempt to process each item in the list
                for (int deviceNumber = 0; ; deviceNumber++)
                {
                    SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfo = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
                    deviceInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInfo);

                    // attempt to read the device info from the list, if this fails, we're at the end of the list
                    if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceList, deviceNumber, ref deviceInfo))
                    {
                        deviceCount = deviceNumber - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

I get 3 as the number of cores, not 2.

Also, in terms of the number of threads this system will support adequately, is that cores x processors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure supposition but could it be:

1. 2 Core with 4 threads implies hyper threading
2. System properties are referring 4 processors => its reading the number of hyper threads available as 'logical single thread processors'
3. Your loop starts at 0 so you're still seeing 4.